# How can I unmask data from client using python

Tags: python, sockets, webserver

I'm writing my own server using python that gets data from the client and I've read online that the client masks its data when sending to the server. I've got the whole handshaking thing down but I just haven't found a code that will unmask the packet. I've found a code that claims to do this but its just not working for me. Is there a pre-made function or package that does this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Down below is my code:

```
# -----------------LISTEN FOR INCOMING DATA FUNCTION----------------- #

def listening_for_msgs(conn):
while True:
    try:
        rcv_msg = conn.recv(1024) #conn is the connection to the client
        rcv_msg_str = str(rcv_msg[:].decode("utf-8"))
        rcv_msg_list = rcv_msg_str.split('\r\n')
        if rcv_msg_list[0] == 'GET /echo HTTP/1.1':
            HandshakeThread = startHandshakeThread(rcv_msg_str, conn)
            HandshakeThread.start()
        else:
            print(unmask_data(rcv_msg))
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        unmask_data(rcv_msg)

# -----------------UNMASKING CLIENTS PACKET FUNCTION----------------- #  

def unmask_data(rcv_msg):
    # as a simple server, we expect to receive:
    #    - all data at one go and one frame
    #    - one frame at a time
    #    - text protocol
    #    - no ping pong messages
data = bytearray(rcv_msg)
if len(data) < 6:
    raise Exception("Error reading data")
# FIN bit must be set to indicate end of frame
assert(0x1 == (0xFF & data[0]) >> 7)
# data must be a text frame
# 0x8 (close connection) is handled with assertion failure
assert(0x1 == (0xF & data[0]))

# assert that data is masked
assert(0x1 == (0xFF & data[1]) >> 7)
datalen = (0x7F & data[1])

# print("received data len %d" %(datalen,))

str_data = ''
if datalen > 0:
    mask_key = data[2:6]
    masked_data = data[6:(6 + datalen)]
    unmasked_data = [masked_data[i] ^ mask_key[i % 4] for i in     range(len(masked_data))]
    str_data = str(bytearray(unmasked_data))
return str_data
```

Comment: What you mean by _not working_ ? Please be specific !

Comment: "I've found a code that claims to do this but its just not working for me". Can you also add some details about the expected behavior, and what is actually happening?

Comment: After some debugging turned out I was getting the data I needed but I didnt assign the function to a variable to get the return str_data from the function. Thanks for help though :)

Comment: I will update my code soon

Comment: Also, make sure you properly paste code. Right now the indentation looks off, and there is no way anyone can fix that and be 100% sure that it's the same as what you have in your file.

Comment: I have updated my code :)

Comment: I've rollback your replacement of the question by a solution. Please find your solution in the revision history and post it as an answer of its own.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm writing my own server using python that gets data from the client and I've read online that the client masks its data when sending to the server.

I recommend that you read again and maybe use additional resources. You are mixing in your code ideas from normal web requests with WebSocket connections. The masking is relevant only for the WebSocket connection. Describing how WebSockets masking works, how a WebSocket connection gets established from a web request and why WebSockets are not the same as plain sockets etc is too broad for this question. If you want to get quick results use [existing libraries](https://www.google.com/search?q=websocket+python). If you want to learn how all this works to write your own code then read the [specification for WebSockets](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455) or study the source code of existing libraries.

Comment: I do agree with you...turned out I was getting the data I needed but I didnt assign the function to a variable to get the return str_data from the function.